# How to choose the discount value in a Markov Decision Process?

Tags: python, markov-process

I reproduced a trivial game found in an [Udacity course](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud820/lessons/684808907/concepts/6512308690923) to experiment Markov Decision Process. I was really surprised to see I found different results. After some research, I saw the discount value I used is very important. When I choose a discount of 0.5, I got different results but with a discount of 0.999, the results are the same (and the solution is optimal).

My question is: how to choose the discount value? In this example, we have an optimal solution with a discount value who is almost 1 but is it the case every time?

If you want to reproduce the experiment, here is the (Python) code I created:

```
import numpy as np
import mdptoolbox

rewar = -0.04

T = np.array([
# 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11
[
[0.9, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1]],
# 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11
[
[0.1, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.2, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.8, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.8],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9]],
# 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11
[
[0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.8, 0.1],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.9]],
# 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10   11
[
[0.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.8, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.2, 0.0, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.1, 0.0],
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.1]]
])

R = np.array([
#  0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10     11
[
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar,  1.00, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[ 0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, -1.00, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[ 0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, -1.00, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar]],
#  0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10     11
[
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar,  1.00, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[ 0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, -1.00, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[ 0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, -1.00, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar]],
#  0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10     11
[
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar,  1.00, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[ 0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, -1.00, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[ 0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, -1.00, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar]],
#  0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9      10     11
[
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar,  1.00, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[ 0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, -1.00, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[ 0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00,  0.00],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar],
[rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar, -1.00, rewar, rewar, rewar, rewar]]
])

discount = 0.1

pi = mdptoolbox.mdp.PolicyIteration(T, R, discount, eval_type=1)
pi.run()
print(pi.policy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a response to my question in this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137590/mdp-value-iteration-choosing-gamma): the higher the discount value (also called gamma) is, the farther the algorithm will see. In other terms, you have to choose your discount value in function of what you want to do: if it's important to maximize rewards but you don't care of the time it can spend, so you have to choose a maximum gamma (0.9999999999999...) but if you prefer get your rewards as early as possible, you should take a smaller gamma.

In my case, I wanted to choose the best path to maximize my rewards and the time wasn't important; that's why the better result occur with the maximum gamma.